# Get-MessageTracking logs for multiple users

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

We've been given a task to get stats on whether 6000+ Contacts have been used in the last 30 days.

We're on Exchange 2013 CU9

So obviously

```
$ht = Get-TransportService *EXC*
$ht | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients user@domain.com -EventId send
```

So I'm writing a function to allow us to put single addresses into the above and if we want also feed in a list or CSV. that's easy enough.

But with over 6000 to search on, and 32 Transport servers with 30 day so of logs this is going to take an incredibly long time.

Just wondering if anyone had seen this issue before and come up with a way of speeding things up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better just to collect the raw logs and parse those with the Log Parser studio https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Log-Parser-Studio-cd458765 which will perform much better.